# How can I recover my encrypted data from a Sandisk Secure Access

Tags: encryption, decryption

I had saved my all important and personal data on sandisk secure access 2.0 on 16gb pen drive cruzer but after 1.5 month when I connect my pen drive to the system, it asked me to generate new passwords, which I did, but I was not able to see my stuff. But in other sandisk secure access folder I have all files encrypted.

How can I decrypt those files?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not tech support. If you recreated your passwords, then you likely wiped the existing files.

Comment: I Had all my files but all are encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

The downside to encrypting your data, is that if you lose your password, and it wasn't an easy one; it's pretty much game over.

As you made the password (you did, right?), try any password you ever made. If that fails, try using a script that brute forces the top 10 000 most used passwords, there are password lists scattered all over the itnernet. If that fails your last resort may be to brute-force the password, [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) has lots of great offline password cracking tools.

Note: Brute-forcing passwords can take a LONG time (we're talking anything from an hour to 300 billion years if you have a decent password) if your password is anywhere above 5-6 characters. You can test how long it would take to bruteforce a certain password on this website: [www.howsecureismypassword.net](https://howsecureismypassword.net/).

Comment: www.howsecureismypassword.net seems to only take into account the length, but since it doesn't say _anything_ about how it gets its number, I really have no idea. I would **HIGHLY** recommend [zxcvbn](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html) instead.